# If I configure a s3 bucket for static website hosting, then can I upload assets to it through API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have an s3 bucket which I've configured for static website hosting, now I frequently have to change assets of my website, 
I already have a custom tool to upload assets to my other bucket is it possible to upload files to my s3 bucket through AWS API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload to S3 bucket using AWS-SDK.

NPM package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

```
            // Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
            var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
            // Set the region 
            AWS.config.update({ region: 'REGION' });

            // Create S3 service object
            s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

            const s3 = new AWS.S3();
            const params = {
                Bucket: S3_BUCKET, //bucket name
                Key: `${s3Folder}/${filename}`, // type is not required
                Body: base64, //image base64
                ACL: 'public-read',
                ContentEncoding: 'base64', // required
                ContentType: `image/${fileType}` // required. Notice the back ticks
            }

            let location = '';
            let key = '';
            try {
                const { Location, Key } = await s3.upload(params).promise();
                location = Location;
                key = Key;
                console.log({ location, key })
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error", error)
            }
```

Read more @ AWS Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html

Comment: oh ok, I'll try it, btw my current custom tool uses signed requests to upload files but that's not working, am I missing a setting or it will not work with a bucket configured for static hosting ? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff

Comment: try dumping assets in another bucket and use assets from that bucket for your static website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a perfectly acceptable way to upload new assets, not how I do it, but it should work just fine, ultimately however you choose to upload those assets, chances are under the covers it is using the same API calls anyway.

Comment: Its not working though, I had a look at this and according to it once we switch to static hosting only GET and HEAD requests work https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html#WebsiteRestEndpointDiff